# Remove Chrome apps from macOS Launchpad? Gmail, Google Drive, Google Search, YouTube

Tags: macos, google-chrome

After installing Chrome for macOS, then launching the Mac's Launchpad, annoyingly Chrome seems to now additionally install the following apps:

- Gmail
- Google Drive
- Google Search
- Youtube

[image: Extra Google apps added to Launchpad]

These aren't actually "apps"... they seem to only open the relevant website in Google Chrome.

I do not want these extra Google apps on my system. I did not want them to be installed when I downloaded Google Chrome.

How can I remove these apps from OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing Chrome installs the extra Google apps in the user Applications directory:

`~/Applications/Chrome Apps/`

`/Users/YOUR_USER/Applications/Chrome Apps/`

Note that this is your *user* Applications directory, not the main system Applications directory.

Move the `Chrome Apps` folder to the Trash, and Empty the Trash. The extra Google apps will then be removed from your Launchpad.

[image: Location of extra google apps.]

Answer (score -1):

Download Appcleaner install the app,
open appcleaner, open Finder and go to applications and drag the apps to appcleaner to remove them.
***Do not remove native apps :)

you can also use CleanMyMac...

Comment: Appcleaner is a terrible app.